# How to make selected function permanent?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is the code i use to make sticky or absolute navbar. It is working very well but i have 1 question. I want it to be permanent like if i choose sticky it will be sticky even if i refresh the page. It will be sticky to the moment I choose the other option. How it can be done?
Thanks in advance! Sorry for my English.

```
<div id="menu-sticky-right">
    <img style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="myFunction()" src="https://i.imgur.com/Ed3FO1w.png" width="15" height="15">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <img style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="myFunction2()" src="https://i.imgur.com/MDg7ZDp.png" width="15" height="15">
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            document.getElementById('menu-sticky').style.cssText = 'position: absolute;';
        }
    </script>
    <script>
        function myFunction2() {
            document.getElementById('menu-sticky').style.cssText = 'position: fixed;';
        }
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: use cookies or browser storage to keep the value in the local browser. Another solution is to store it in the backend.

Comment: I am new in these things and I dont know how to do it for my site users.

Comment: `localStorage` would be your best bet for something like this.

Answer (score 2):

In order to keep informations between page refreshes, you can use `window.sessionStorage` (which will be cleared when the browser is closed), or `window.localStorage` (which keeps data forever).

Both have `.setItem(name, value)` and `.getItem(name)`, which can be used respectively to store an information (a variable), and to get it back. You could for example use those to store a boolean variable `isSticky`.

**See the Storage API documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API).**

Your code could look like this:

```html
<div id="menu-sticky-right">
    <img style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="myFunction()" src="https://i.imgur.com/Ed3FO1w.png" width="15" height="15">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <img style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="myFunction2()" src="https://i.imgur.com/MDg7ZDp.png" width="15" height="15">
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            window.localStorage.setItem('isAbsolute', true);
            document.getElementById('menu-sticky').style.cssText = 'position: absolute;';
        }
        function myFunction2() {
            window.localStorage.setItem('isAbsolute', false);
            document.getElementById('menu-sticky').style.cssText = 'position: fixed;';
        }

        var isAbsolute = window.localStorage.getItem('isAbsolute');
        if (isAbsolute) {
            document.getElementById('menu-sticky').style.cssText = 'position: absolute;';
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('menu-sticky').style.cssText = 'position: fixed;';
        }
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the information but i litterly don't know how to do this i researched a lot in internet.

Comment: @KraskataMiVikat I edited my answer with an example code!

Comment: Now by default it will be fixed and if i choose absolute it will be absolute forever? (Whitin i want to choose fixed again...) Even if i refresh/close the browser?

Comment: @KraskataMiVikat The first time an user will access your page, getItem() will return false, which will make the menu absolute by default. But otherwise, yes, it will stay even if you refresh or close the browser!
If you want by default to fix the menu, rename `isSticky` to `isAbsolute` for better code readability, and flip the two `document.getElementById(...)` lines at the bottom of the code

Comment: Ok, but now when i click on
<img style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="myFunction()" src="https://i.imgur.com/Ed3FO1w.png" width="15" height="15">
It have to make it absolute, it makes it absolute but after refresh it is fixed again ;(

Comment: @KraskataMiVikat I changed again the code, can you retry?

Comment: It is absolute by default know but when i click on the second option to make it fixed and refresh the page it doesnt stay fixed, it is absolute again.

Comment: @KraskataMiVikat You might want to read again the documentation for the Storage API [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API), everything is pretty clear there!

Comment: I read it and when i tried to do it (make it to save the selected option) id didnt worked... :( I cant understand this very well. I litterly want to make it to save the selected option but it doesnt work when i make it becouse i might dont make it how it is supposed to be.